# this error is not printed in devtools in firefox

Tags: firefox, runtime-error, preact

```js
 const { Component, h, render } = window.preact
 
 class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
   this.setState({ stage:'choose-lesson' })
  }
  render() {
   if (this.state.stage == 'choose-lesson') {
    return h(TicketChoiceMenu, {})
   }
   else {
    return h('b',{},'oh')
   }
  }
 }
 
 function TicketChoiceMenu() {
  console.log('AAA')
  un = de.fi.ned // this is not reported in FireFox
  console.log('BBB')
  return 'CCC'
 }
 
 render(h(App), root)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/preact@6.4.0/dist/preact.min.js"></script>
<div id=root>...</div>
```

What I can see is `AAA` printed in the console, but not `BBB`. I tested and retested, and then came up with this minimal example.

How to fix this? I need to get the errors reported or otherwise developing becomes very difficult.

Comment: Preact V6 is ancient. Have you tried this with the latest 8.x release?